# Empty HTML page after OTA install on Symbian

Tags: symbian, nokia, ota

I have some quite nasty issue I couldn't solve so far.

Whenever I do installation of Symbian application on Nokia platform, the browser loads blank HTML page, and needs to be closed manually.

It doesn't happens on WAP push installations - only on direct link installations via the browser.
It happens on installations both from JAD and JAR.

I tried specifying manifest entries, etc... - nothing helped.

Any idea how to prevent this blank page, as it confusing the users?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it happen with all device?, i mean have you tried with another one, i think its the OS thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that the content types of the downloaded files are correct:

For `.jad`, the content type should be `text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor`
For `.jar`, the content type should be `application/java-archive`

Setting the content type according to a file's extension is usually something you configure in your HTTP server.